# Excel C# event new row

Tags: c#, excel, events

Is there an event that can detect when the active row count of an Excel Sheet increases by 1? If not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you are using Interop, than stop using it. Use NPOI.

Comment: http://npoi.codeplex.com/ " POI is an open source project which can help you read/write xls, doc, ppt files. It has a wide application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the closest thing is the [**`SelectionChange` event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.docevents_event.selectionchange.aspx). You can get the `Rows.Count` property of the `Target` argument:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private int rowsBefore = 0;

void SomeMethod() {
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[0];
    ws.SelectionChange += new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(ws_SelectionChange);
}

void ws_SelectionChange(Excel.Range Target) {
    int rowsNow = Target.Rows.Count;
    if (rowsNow > rowsBefore) {
        // do stuff
    }
    rowsBefore = rowsNow;
}
```